# Evento dispara somente de segunda, após sequência de ações do usuário

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, jquery-1.6

Tenho um formulário em que existe uma tabela. Na parte de baixo desta, existem botões para manipular as linhas da tabela, sendo que somente as selecionadas serão afetadas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Passos para reproduzir problema**

### [jsfiddle para verificar o problema](http://jsfiddle.net/masbicudo/7pEPK/2/)

<sup>[result do fiddle para testar no IE 8](http://jsfiddle.net/masbicudo/7pEPK/2/embedded/result/)</sup>

1. clique em qualquer caixa de forma que ela fique cor de laranja
2. clique em um dos botões de comando
3. clique novamente na caixa para desselecionar a linha

   Não vai funcionar!
4. clique de novo, para desselecionar a linha

   Agora funciona!

Esse fiddle já está com o código javascript muito bem isolado, não tem nem scroll no fiddle (na parte do script, que é onde acho que está o problema)... mas ainda assim não consegui resolver o problema.

## Questão

Como fazer a caixa desselecionar no primeiro clique?

Por favor, se você sabe a solução, me explique... não coloque apenas código... eu gostaria muito de saber o porque disso não estar funcionando.

**Browsers que eu testei que apresentam o problema:** Chrome 34, Firefox 28, IE 8

Pra falar a verdade, me preocupo muito em resolver para o chrome, um pouco menos para o FF, e nem um pouco para o IE 8... só mencionei o IE 8 para mostrar que o problema é consistente entre os browseres.

**Notas:**

Verifiquei que ao remover as linhas abaixo, funciona da forma que eu quero... quase...
São duas linhas iguais a esta:

```
.bind("blur mouseout", restore)
```

Entretanto, dessa forma eu perco o mouse-out, que serve para limpar o ícone que é colocado dentro da caixa alaranjada indicando quais as linhas afetadas, pois nem sempre uma linha selecionada poderá ser afetada por um comando.

Comment: Você tem algum código para quando o botão recebe um click? i.e.: quer usar o event handler `click`para correr código quando o botão fôr clicado? Ou só usa o `mousehover` e `mouseout`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Muito provavelmente seu problema está no `blur`. Siga os seguintes passos:

1. clique em qualquer caixa de forma que ela fique cor de laranja
2. clique em um dos botões de comando

   2.1. transfira o foco para outro lugar (clique em outra janela, use <kbd>Tab</kbd> várias vezes, etc)
3. clique novamente na caixa para desselecionar a linha

   Agora funciona!

### Explicação

Quando você **não** transfere o foco, as seguintes coisas acontecem:

1. Quando você clica, o foco *ainda está* no botão de comando;
2. A primeira coisa a acontecer, portanto, é o evento `blur` nesse botão;
3. Esse evento causa um `restore`, que **muda o html do elemento sendo clicado**;
4. Como esse elemento acabou de mudar, ele *provavelmente* ainda não está sujeito ao `live`;
5. O clique acontece de fato; como o elemento ainda não está sujeito ao `live` ele não registra o clique.

### Proposta de solução (imperfeita):

Se o evento que causou o restore não é um `blur`, force-o:

```
var restore = function(e) {
    if ( e.type != "blur" )
        $(this).blur();
    $("#columns .selected .selector").get(0).innerHTML
        = "<i>&nbsp;</i>";
};
```

[Exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/7pEPK/4/). Essa não é a solução ideal (ex.: se o usuário transferiu o foco pro botão, passou o mouse por cima sem querer, depois apertou "espaço" ele vai se surpreender do botão ter perdido o foco), mas serve de base para uma solução melhor. Outro cenário que pode surpreender o usuário é se ele usou o teclado para acionar o botão de comando (i.e. ele possui o foco, e nunca recebeu um `mouseout`) e o mouse para tentar de-selecionar a linha (i.e. o `blur` do botão de comando será ativado) - nesse caso, o bug permanecerá.

Não consigo pensar numa solução melhor, de modo que o ideal seria *não alterar* o html do elemento sendo clicado, de modo a evitar esse *glitch*. Receio não ter nada a sugerir a respeito, mas se conseguir pensar em algo melhor volto a postar aqui.

---

### Atualização

Montei um exemplo sem mexer no markup nem no CSS, que funciona corretamente exceto por um pequeno detalhe visual. Ele se baseia no proposto acima - de não mexer no html durante um `blur`:

```
var showIcon = function() {
    // Esconde o elemento presente
    $("#columns .selected .selector i").hide();

    // Obtém o ícone; se ele não existe, cria-o
    var icone = $("#columns .selected .selector .icone");
    if ( icone.length == 0 )
        icone = $('<span class="icone"></span>').appendTo($("#columns .selected .selector"));

    // Atualiza-o para ficar igual ao botão de comando
    icone.html($(this).html()).show();
}

var restore = function() {
    // Mostra de novo o elemento vazio e esconde o ícone
    $("#columns .selected .selector i").show();
    $("#columns .selected .selector .icone").hide();
};
```

[Exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/7pEPK/5/). Como não estamos alterando o html do elemento (o que confirmei ser o suficiente pro clique falhar - seja usando `live` ou no jQuery 1.7+ usando `on`) o glitch não ocorre. Só faltou posicionar o elemento com CSS pra ele ficar dentro do quadrado.

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado pela ajuda... é isso mesmo: não vou poder alterar o HTML do elemento durante o blur. Eu já havia testado com outras formas de ouvir o evento click, inclusive atribuindo uma função diretamente à propriedade `onclick`... o evento click simplesmente não é chamado.

Comment: Resolvi da seguinte forma: usei um `setTimeout` com 0 milissegundos para setar o html, e dentro do método `restore` tive que fazer uma adaptação para o evento `mouseout` não ser chamado com o elemento filho do próprio botão. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7pEPK/6/)... mas ainda não ficou perfeito. =\ vou continuar tentando nessa linha pra ver no que dá.

Comment: Acho que consegui finalmente: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7pEPK/7/)... graças à sua resposta! =D

Answer (score 2):

Quando você faz um clic no `button` ele dispara também um evento `focus` (http://jsfiddle.net/Xqfnu/).

Uma opção, parecida com a ideia do @mgibsonbr seria disparar um `blur` no momento do click. Isto resolve o problema para mim no Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/Xqfnu/1/

```
var clic = function () {
   $(this).blur();
}

//...

// UP
$("#move-column-up")
    .bind("click", clic)
    .bind("focus mouseover", showIcon)
    .bind("blur mouseout", restore)

// DOWN
$("#move-column-down")
    .bind("click", clic)
    .bind("focus mouseover", showIcon)
    .bind("blur mouseout", restore)
```

Já agora, e sem ter a certeza porque tem o `e.preventDefault()`, se colocar `type="button"` no button ele deixa de fazer submit ao `form` cada vez que clica.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica... acabei resolvendo com um setTimeout pra mudar o HTML de forma assíncrona: http://jsfiddle.net/7pEPK/7/ Não tenho certeza se isso é completamente recomendável... mas funcionou. O que você acha, será que vou ter problemas com essa minha solução?